# What happens when service worker cache is maxed out?

Tags: javascript, caching, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

When I am using service worker cache and it reaches its cap limit, what happens then? Does it return an error when trying to cache additional things, or does it natively work by overwriting infrequently used or too old files already?

Would like to know this in order to know how to implement it better, before I switch to workbox, ofc, that is.

Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Browser_storage_limits_and_eviction_criteria

Comment: Nice. I don't think I am using IndexedDB at the moment however, I'm using the Web API Cache https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache ... Although if that has better performance for saving media / script resources, I might consider using it. Thanks for the reply though, I'm just looking at plausible scenarios.

Comment: That articles treats of different API that do store on the user's disk. Cache API is one of these and is explicitely cited.

Comment: Gotcha! In such case, I did read the Storage Limits addendum and it answers many of my doubts. Thanks a lot.